# How to add a React Key on a object

Tags: javascript, reactjs

So I have a object that I need to put a react key due to the virtual dom, I know its very easy to add a react key to an array using map, but what about objects?

Any feedback would be greatly appreciated.

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';

export default class ViewAllAnswers extends Component {
  render() {
    const self = this;
    const submittedAnswers = self.props.submittedAnswers;
    var submittedAnswerSlides = [];

    for (var key in submittedAnswers) {
      if (submittedAnswers.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        submittedAnswerSlides.push(
           <div className="flex">
            <div>
              <div className="flex answer p20">
               {submittedAnswers[key].answer}
              </div>
            </div>
           </div>
        );
      }
    }


        return (
          <div className="paper">
            {submittedAnswerSlides}
          </div>
        )

  }
}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You are rendering a list of children contained in the submittedAnswerSlides list, and React wants each child in that list to have a unique key so that it knows when a component enters or exits from that list.

You can use the key from your submittedAnswers hash as the key for each child in the submittedAnswerSlides list. The key must be specified on the outer-most element:

```
for (var key in submittedAnswers) {
    if (submittedAnswers.hasOwnProperty(key) {
        submittedAnswerSlides.push(
            <div key={key} className="flex">
               // rest of your code stays the same
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: this worked perfectly, I am actually let down that I didn't even think to try using the hash.

Answer (score -1):

objects are not consecutively indexed like arrays are.

if you want to put keys on your object, you have to turn it into a array, and then you can put keys on it.

Comment: A great suggestion! Giving some example code with this would be super helpful!

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, I am not sure if converting a mutable object into an array during the render method is a great idea (mainly from a performance perspective). Regardless thank you for the input!